# Finding transverse shear center in a thin circular section: $\int{\frac{Q_z}{I_z}R}d\theta=2V_y\int{\frac{sin\theta}{\theta+0.5sin 2\theta}}d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, algebra-precalculus

$dA=tds=Rtd\theta\space$ where t is the thickness and $V_y$ is a constant
$$Q_z=R^2tsin\theta$$
$$I_z=\frac{R^3t}{2}(\theta+\frac{sin2\theta}{2})$$
$$f=V_y\int{\frac{Q_z}{I_z}R}d\theta=2V_y\int{\frac{sin\theta}{\theta+0.5sin 2\theta}}d\theta$$

Is there any possible way to solve this integral symbolically?

[image]